# "Lost in transaction"

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ropsten, txpool

Yesterday I sent this tx on Ropsten network. It is a transfer for 999 ethers.

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:"0x8c60d40a2e848251d139fc2b0b6b770bb3351ffd", to:"0xf9e33261328a1cdc62d3dc6b95880656a1f2a5d9", value: web3.toWei(999, "ether"), gas:4700000, gasPrice: 10000000000});
    0x86329f1a1022c4d7cfe7c66b319c31481d66c83e0554980ec1b3e567d6f79c97
```

Transaction **0x86329f1a1022c4d7cfe7c66b319c31481d66c83e0554980ec1b3e567d6f79c97** became lost. First 10 hours was seeing on etherscan https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x86329f1a1022c4d7cfe7c66b319c31481d66c83e0554980ec1b3e567d6f79c97 as a pending tx, but then it just disappeared and it doesn't exist anymore.

Is there any explanation to such a behaviour? Is no guarantee for a sent tx to be mined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote to answer found [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18736/are-pending-transactions-dropped-and-reinstated):

> Normally, the transactions live there until mined, but because computers have finite memory and processing power, the transaction pool is, by necessity, also of a finite size. Transactions that have not been mined may be evicted from memory if the transaction pool is full (I assume the ordering is implementation dependent -- presumably, higher value transactions are kept). So your transaction probably got evicted from Etherscan's transaction pool, but was "recirculated" by another node after Etherscan's transaction pool freed up some memory.

Also, it appears that you have succesfully completed the transaction about 30 minutes ago with the hash `0x8b887813e9a2301e35ccafe944850a9356489bb04fa731c1ca14ea96fc6d47fa`. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x8b887813e9a2301e35ccafe944850a9356489bb04fa731c1ca14ea96fc6d47fa

Comment: This one is a new tx for the same amount 24h later

Comment: @JuanIgnacioPérezSacristán yeah I figured it was a new transaction since it was so delayed, but thought it was relevant to point out its success.

Comment: @JuanIgnacioPérezSacristán please accept and close this question if this answer was sufficient, otherwise, are there other points I can try to clarify from my answer?